# Jquery date picker in Meteor.js

Tags: jquery-ui, meteor

I am trying to use jquery datepicker in my project, but I want to show it when the user in editing mode. When I use it without if statement, it works perfect, but when I put in if statement, it does not render. How can I solve this?

This is the part of my template

```
   {{#if editing_duedate}}
        <input class="datepicker"  name="date">
    {{else}}
        <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="eventduedate">
                     {{duedate}}
                </div>
        </div>
    {{/if}}
```

This where I render datepicker

```
Template.assignmenttodositem.rendered = function() {
$('.datepicker').datepicker();    
 };
```

This is my template events

```
Template.assignmenttodositem.events({

......
'dblclick .eventduedate':function(evt,tmpl){
    evt.preventDefault();
    Session.set('editingduedate', this._id);
}
..........
```

This is where I check if statement

```
Template.assignmenttodositem.editing_duedate = function () {
    return Session.equals('editingduedate', this._id);
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<template name="assignmenttodositem">
  {{#if editing_duedate}}
    {{> datepicker}}
  {{else}}
    ...
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="datepicker">
  <input class="datepicker"  name="date">
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.datepicker.rendered=function(){
  this.$('.datepicker').datepicker();
};
```

The `rendered` callback is executed only once when your template instance is inserted in the DOM : triggering the `datepicker` initialization in the enclosing template containing the `#if` statement is not going to work because when it is executed, we are in the `else` state so the input is not there yet.

To solve this problem simply, just move the datepicker in its own template (this has always been considered a good design pattern in programming anyway, whenever you can, decompose your main task in smaller easier solvable tasks), this way its rendered callback will get executed at appropriate time.

Answer (score 1):

`Rendered` is executed only once, when template is rendered. 
In that time `else` part is not put to HTML so `.datepicker` cannot be found.
You need to check whether `editinduedate` variable is updated and then create datePicker component.

```
Template.assignmenttodositem.rendered = function() {
   var self = this;
   this.autorun(function(){
     if(Session.equals("editingduedate", self.data._id )){
       $('.datepicker').datepicker();    
     }
   })
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the datepicker in it's own template. Then initialize the datepicker in  template.datepicker.rendered . If you forget the 'this' context, it will not work. Make sure your template.datepicker.rendered includes the following

```
this.$('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

where #datepiker refers to id='datepicker' of the datepicker in html.